# Ruby unable to parse Json

Tags: json, ruby

**The Problem**

Trying to convert json file into a hash. I get parsing error. This has been driving me nuts for days. More confusingly that my code works on one computer, but that same exact code does not work on the other.

I've used various contents of the JSON file itself. Even simple one line json fails. Oddly enough, if I copy/paste that same JSON contents into a literal string instead of parsing from file, it works just fine -_- .

**My Code**

```
require 'json'
read_json = File.read('DirectRoutingTable.json')
hashed_json = JSON.parse(read_json)
puts hashed_json
```

**Contents of JSON File**

{ "name": "manni"}

**Error message**

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/common.rb:155:in \`parse': 757: unexpected token at '{ "name": "manni"} (JSON::ParserError)

'

from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json/common.rb:155:in \`parse'

from 5example.rb:3:in \`<main>'
```

**Works on my computer - Specs**

- ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
- json (1.8.3)

**Fails on VM where I need it to run - Specs**

- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
- json (1.8.3)

---

**UPDATE** 3pm
So I decided to loop through each character having each character pass through an if condition regex ([A-Za-z0-9:-_ \n{}\"\']). Basically I include all characters that I use in the json. One character gets excluded which prints as nothing in console, the ordinal of the character is 65279, and it is right in the beginning of my string. When I parse json excluding the first character, it works just fine. So my inelegant solution to get it working is to change the file read line to

```
File.read('DirectRoutingTable.json')[1..-1]
```

So 2 questions

- What the hell is character 65279?
- Why does File.read() include this character?

**Code I used to determine the problem**
    require 'json'
    read_json = File.read('foo.json')

```
new_string = ''

puts '********************************************'
counter = 0

read_json.split("").each do |ch|
  print 'Character Number: ' + counter.to_s + "\n"
  print "Character: '" +  ch + "'\n"
  print "Character value: '" +  ch.ord.to_s + "'\n"
  if ch =~ /[A-Za-z0-9:\-\_ \n\{\}\"\']/
    puts 'Matches new string: Yes'
  else
    puts 'Matches new string: No'
  end
  puts '*'
  counter = counter + 1
end
```

**Output**

```
Character Number: 0
Character: ''
Character value: '65279'
Matches regex: No
*
Character Number: 1
Character: '{'
Character value: '123'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 2
Character: ' '
Character value: '32'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 3
Character: '"'
Character value: '34'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 4
Character: 'n'
Character value: '110'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 5
Character: 'a'
Character value: '97'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 6
Character: 'm'
Character value: '109'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 7
Character: 'e'
Character value: '101'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 8
Character: '"'
Character value: '34'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 9
Character: ':'
Character value: '58'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 10
Character: ' '
Character value: '32'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 11
Character: '"'
Character value: '34'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 12
Character: 'm'
Character value: '109'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 13
Character: 'a'
Character value: '97'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 14
Character: 'n'
Character value: '110'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 15
Character: 'n'
Character value: '110'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 16
Character: 'i'
Character value: '105'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 17
Character: '"'
Character value: '34'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 18
Character: '}'
Character value: '125'
Matches regex: Yes
*
Character Number: 19
Character: '
'
Character value: '10'
Matches regex: Yes
*
```

Comment: Could you provide us the DirectRoutingTable.json?

Comment: The file contents simply contain (without single quotes) '{ "name": "manni"}'

Comment: I guess, it has something to do with line endings.

Comment: Thanks! I tought the same than @OmidKamangar

Comment: @OmidKamangar Seems to have nothing to with line endings. Has to do with first character in string returned from File.read

Comment: @HugoFarji Seems to have nothing to with line endings. Has to do with first character in string returned from File.read

Comment: @manni Your aproach is really good man, take a look at the response of HomePlaneR, probably you would need to do that, maybe you can omit the character from ruby and not from notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"65279" character is byte order mark.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Some parsers might have issues when it is present in the input stream. You can remove it from your JSON file with a text editor like Notepad++.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you @HomePlaneR

Now knowing that the mystery character causing all the issues is a BOM the real elegant solution is reading the file properly. The following code works.

```
require 'json'
json_file = File.open('DirectRoutingTable.json', 'r:bom|utf-8')
read_json = json_file.read
hashed_json = JSON.parse(read_json)
puts hashed_json
```